# Python - group by columns A + B and count row values for columns C for each unique occurrence of A + B

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I hate having to ask but I have searched for many hours for a solution to the this problem. I have got close with Pandas but not close enough. It is driving me mad as I know it must be possible!
So i have a data_frame like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
              {'Path': ['Yellow','Yellow','Blue','Green','Yellow','Blue','Yellow','Yellow'], 
               'Type': ['Image','Video','Image','Video','Video','Video','Image','Image'], 
               'Category': [A,A,B,A,B,A,C,C],
              },
```

I have tried:

```
A = df[(df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Type'] == 'Image')]
A = A.groupby(['Path']).size().reset_index(name='Count of A')
```

But this only returns the count for one 'Category' and its 'Type' per unique 'Path' at a time. Ideally I want to group the data so that it outputs something similar to this:

```
Path   | Type  | Count of A | Count of B | Count of C |
Yellow | Image |      1     |            |     2      |
       | Video |      1     |      1     |            |
Green  | Image |            |            |            |
       | Video |      1     |            |            |
Blue   | Image |            |      1     |            |
       | Video |      1     |            |            |
```

Even if I could do one Path at a time that would be better than what I am currently outputting.

I hope someone can see the solution and put me out of my misery!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still using `groupby`  + `value_counts`

```
    df.groupby(['Path','Type']).Category.apply(pd.value_counts).unstack().fillna('')
Out[121]: 
              A  B  C
Path   Type          
Blue   Image     1   
       Video  1      
Green  Video  1      
Yellow Image  1     2
       Video  1  1
```

Or we using `pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),index=['Path','Type'],columns=['Category'],values='index',aggfunc='count')
Out[123]: 
Category        A    B    C
Path   Type                
Blue   Image  NaN  1.0  NaN
       Video  1.0  NaN  NaN
Green  Video  1.0  NaN  NaN
Yellow Image  1.0  NaN  2.0
       Video  1.0  1.0  NaN
```